# Constraining other application's window sizes through Qt Application

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, qt, pyside

I'm looking for a way in Qt to constrain other application window's (some will not be Qt) so that when maximized don't overlap my Qt application.  Essentially I want to create the Windows Taskbar.  I'd like the applications edge to dock to the appropriate edge of my Qt Taskbar in the same way that applications dock to the Windows taskbar when they are maximized.  I envision this taskbar to exist along the top edge of the screen, but would like to allow users to decide which edge it will live on.

I know it isn't hard to make a window that is always on top it's more the auto docking issue I'm having a hard time figuring out.

I'm right now only looking to accomplish this on Windows.

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Detailed explanation on how to do it would be too long for an answer here, but MSDN documentation on [SHAppBarMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762108%28VS.85%29.aspx) should get you started. Taskbar created like that can even be part of winows taskbar ;)